# Solspace Comment Upload allowing all file types

Tags: add-on, file-uploads, solspace

I am using the Solspace Comment Upload extension to allow users to attach files to their comments. I would like to restrict the uploading of file types to only the MIME types listed in mimes.php. Currently it is allowing any file type to be uploaded, but the system seems to be restricting the download of file types that are not listed in mimes.php. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built in parameter to limit file types, but have a look at this old forum post which describes where in the ext code you can look to modify the allowed upload types.

http://www.solspace.com/forums/viewthread/13764/